# Cleaning AD from import-CSV - process line by line or another way/functions - improving code

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I've got a CSV-file from HR with aprox 1000 lines (employees) that I feed to AD with Powershell.
This works, but I am a bit uncertain if I am doing this the right way.

This are my major concerns:

- I am setting the attributes one at a time. Should I put the "changes" into an some kind of array/hasthable/object and do it all at once at the end of the script? But How? "New-Object"?
- Should I use functions? But how can I return values (and continue based on the result from the function)?

All programming hints, corrections would be GREATLY appreciated. I really understand this wonderful community of knowledgable people so, let me have it. If you have the time please tell me how I can do this better..

This is my code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
Add-PSSnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

$file = "\Scripts\employees.csv"        #  Location of the input file
$file2 = "\Scripts\employees2.csv"      # Temp file
$logfile = "\Scripts\logfile.txt"   # log file
remove-item $logfile -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Get-Content $file | Out-File -Encoding UTF8  $file2                         # Convert to UTF8 (we don't touch the original inputfile)
$ListEmployees = Import-Csv $file2 -Delimiter ";"                           # Import the file to CSV

foreach ($ListEmployee in $ListEmployees) {
$ListDisplayName = $ListEmployee.firstname + " " + $ListEmployee.lastname

if($ADemployee = Get-QADUser -displayname $ListDisplayName -IncludedProperties employeeid )
{
    ## CHECK NAME
    if($($ADEmployee.displayname) -eq $($ListDisplayName))
    { 
        echo "MATCH: $($ADEmployee.displayname)" 
    }

    ## CHECK COMPANY
    if($($ADEmployee.company) -ne $($ListEmployee.company))
    { 
        echo "       CHANGE   - Company: '$($ADEmployee.company)' to '$($ListEmployee.company)'" 
        Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -Company $($ListEmployee.company) -WhatIf
    }
    else
    {
        echo "       OK       - Company     : no change '$($ListEmployee.company)'"
    }

    ## CHECK OFFICE
    if($($ADEmployee.office) -ne $($ListEmployee.office))
    {
        echo "       CHANGE   - Office '$($ADEmployee.office)' to '$($ListEmployee.office)'"
        Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -Office $($ListEmployee.Office) -WhatIf
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "       OK       - Office      : no change '$($ListEmployee.office)'"
    }

    ## CHECK MOBILE
    if( $listemployee.mobile -match '\S' )
    {
        if($($ADEmployee.mobile) -ne $($ListEmployee.mobile))
        {
            echo "       CHANGE   - Mobile  : '$($ADEmployee.mobile)' to '$($ListEmployee.mobile)'"
            Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -Mobile $($ListEmployee.mobile) -WhatIf
        }
        else
        { 
            echo "       OK       - Mobile      : no change '$($ListEmployee.mobile)'"
        }
    }

    ## CHECK EMPLOYEEID
    if($($ADEmployee.employeeid) -ne $($ListEmployee.employeeid))
    {
        echo "       CHANGE   - EmployeeID: '$($ADEmployee.employeeid)' to '$($ListEmployee.employeeid)'"
        Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -ObjectAttributes @{employeeID = $($ListEmployee.employeeid)} -WhatIf

    }
    else
    {
        echo "       OK       - EmployeeID  : no change '$($ListEmployee.employeeid)'"
    }
    $match++
}
else
{
    if($EXContact = Get-Contact $ListDisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        echo "MATCH CONTACT: $ListDisplayName (contact)"

        ## CHECK MOBILE
        if( $listemployee.mobile -match '\S' )
        {
            if($($EXContact.Mobilephone) -ne $($ListEmployee.mobile))
            { 
                echo "       CHANGE   - Mobile : '$($EXContact.Mobilephone)' to '$($ListEmployee.mobile)'"
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "       OK       - Mobile ; No change ($($ListEmployee.mobile))"
            }
        }

        ## CHECK COMPANY
        if($($EXContact.company) -ne $($ListEmployee.company))
        { 
            echo "       CHANGE   - Company: '$($EXContact.company)' to '$($ListEmployee.company)'"
        }
        else
        {
            echo "     OK       - Company : No change($($ListEmployee.company))"
        }

        ## CHECK OFFICE
        if($($EXContact.office) -ne $($ListEmployee.office))
        { 
            echo "       CHANGE   - Office '$($EXContact.office)' to '$($ListEmployee.office)'"
        }
        else
        {
            echo "       OK       - Office : No Change($($ListEmployee.office))"
        }       
        $contactmatch++
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$ListDisplayName" | Out-File $logfile -Append
        echo "NO MATCH: $ListDisplayName" 
        $nomatch++
    }
}
$i++
}
echo " "
echo "List contains $i accounts"
echo "Accounts: $match matches"
echo "Contacts: $contactmatch"
echo "No Match: $nomatch"
```

And; If you think this is cr*p, tell me! I'd rather hear it from you than you staying silent just to be polite! I am "quite" new to this so I deserve it:)

Comment: Tip - you're using subexpressions too much. The syntax `$( expression )` is only needed in certain cases like when you are trying to access a variable property with a double quoted string `"$( $variable.property )"`. If you are just accessing a property, you don't need to use it, for example you can just do `$ADEmployee.office -eq $ListEmployee.office`.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy! The reason I am using it all over is that it seems that I cannot use it directly when I am echoing output. Would this be an correct assumption?

Comment: This will output the value of the office property `Write-Host $ADEmployee.Office`. However if you want to add text, one way to do it is to use a subexpression `Write-Host "Office: $($ADEmployee.Office)"` or you could use string formatting `Write-Host ("Office: {0}" -f $ADEmployee.Office)`. However if you aren't accessing a property you can just do this `Write-Host "Office: $ADEmployee"` and PowerShell will call the `ToString` method on the object which may or may not have return the data you want.

Comment: Ahh! So to return a variable from a function I simply use write-host from within the function and it will be accessible outside of the function? Thank you!

Comment: Returning a variable from a function is different than echoing it's value on screen. In functions, anything that outputs a value that is not either assigned to a variable or discarded by piping to $null or using Out-Null will be returned from the function. You can also use the return keyword.

Comment: I see. For a second I thought write-host would make the variable accessible from outside the function - of course not. Thank you for explaining Andy. Please know that I am happy for any more pointers/tips if you have the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my opinion :

1) I really think that the problem @mjolinor point is important, and you will meet troubles (I mean need human check) if you don't use one of the identity attributes fixed by Microsoft (samAccountName, userPrincipalName or better objectGuid, objectSid ...) as a key to find your users in Active-Directory.

If it's not possible you perhaps can buid a filter on the top of multiples attributes. If you CSV comes from another LDAP Directory you perhaps can integrate their unique ID in you Schema (in this case see Microsoft Services for UNIX 3.5 (MSFU3.5) schema extensions to Active Directory).

2) Once you find one of your CSV entry in your Active-Directory, you check each attributes, and then replace 'one by one' the ones in your AD with the one in your CSV.

Here my advice will be to check all the differencies between your CSV and AD entry, and them made an unique change into the Directory. In fact, on one différence, I will change them all in one command. I don't know how `Set-QADUser` is written, but in the low level layers all the attributes replacement can be made one shot (LDAP_REPLACE, or in a single ADSI commit)

3) Just a remark : begining PowerShell V2 (Seven, W2K8) an Active-Directory module is given by Microsoft.

Comment: In a perfect world every employee would be required to legally change their name to match thier domain SID as a condition of employment, but you're not going to ge that.  HR and Accounting departments work of of people's names and internally assigned employee numbers, and it's unlikely you'll get them to change to using AD identity references. If you can get them to use both the first name, last name and employee id on the add/change/delete requests that should be sufficient.  If the can enter all three of those wrong, then they'd probably have put in a bad SID or GUID, too.

Comment: I agrre that why I propose a filter to look for the user in the AD.

Comment: The same thing was proposed in the comments of the other answer.

Comment: Yes, there are two answers at the moment, and many comments. @sune ask for an advice and I give mine in a 3 points answer. The second point was not mentionned neither the third. I just think that using comment as answer is just not good.

Comment: Thank you for all your input. I've decided to use both "displayname" and "employeeid". Employeeid has been added to AD via script, but supervised.

Answer (score 2):

Something that seems odd about the whole thing is using display name as your identity reference.  As an identity reference, it't both volatile and potentially ambiguos in AD, and seems a poor choice to use to drive a maintenance script.

Comment: Agreed. What is needed is a guaranteed unique identifier for employes  so the script won't update the wrong accounts.

Comment: I know, so my thought is that I am adding the "employeeID" under strict and manual supervision and base all additions after that on "employeeID". Sounds better?

Comment: That's better, but AD will not guarantee it is unique. When adding new accounts, you'll need to verify that an employeeid isn't already assigned before you give it to the new account.

Comment: If you can get them to continue to provide first and last names along with employeeid, do the initial AD lookup  on the employeeid, then verify the names in AD match what's in your input.

Comment: Thank you for all your input. I've decided to use both "displayname" and "employeeid". Employeeid has been added to AD via script, but supervised.